# Meaning of red line at the end of formula bar Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am writing measures in Power BI and I cannot figure out if this red flag means anything or not. My measures give me the right results, so I am not sure if it means there could be errors etc?

I have shown it on the attached snapshot

[image]

Comment: It tells you in short : The Code you are trying to write is incorrect. Just go back and correct it before you move forward. Even before you test it, It warns you that your code will fail if we decide to run it.

Comment: @OzanSen but it does not fail; that is my confusion

Comment: what you mean it does not fail? You can't create it. It won't accept it as valid code.

Comment: I create measure with the DAX code, it shows me the red in the end, but it works just fine

Comment: Ops! it looks strange. What you did to trick the engine ?

Comment: I did not do anything, I think it is a bad call by the interpreter that should be fixed by MS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shows one red bar for each error line it *thinks* it detects in your DAX. However, the DAX formula bar does make mistakes on valid DAX code and it looks like this is the case here. You might want to share it with MS so they can update the DAX parser if it is definitely valid.